# node app.js file doesn't opens on the command line interface

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, terminal, node-modules

My file name is app.js. I have tried running my javascript file in server using the command *<E:<file path>\node app.js>* . While I run this command, it opens a node server *"<C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\node\bin\node.exe>"*
The thing is I have node already installed. Why is it not opened directly in the terminal?

Comment: What do you mean by opening a node server?

Comment: can you provide some more details? some screenshots that might help ?